# Perl Graphics Command Works in Command Line, But Doesn't Work as a CGI

Tags: perl, cgi, gd

We have an old Perl script that generates a PNG graphic file to show a line-chart in an internal web page. We use that Perl script as a CGI in an Apache web server. It works fine for many years. Recently we want to move the Apache web server from a Windows 7 computer to a Windows 10 computer. And the problem starts. The Perl script cannot use Chart::Lines program module to generate the graphic file. Somehow when I convert the Perl script from a CGI into a plain Perl script and run in a command line, it works fine.

I have tracked down the problem to a line in C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Chart\Base.pm:

```
sub _draw_right_legend {
  .
  .
  # draw the point
  $self->{'gd_obj'}->line(int(($x3+$x2)/2), $y2, int(($x3+$x2)/2), $y2, gdBrushed);
  .
  .
}
```

Seem like the use of "gdBrushed" can trigger the problem when the Perl script is running as a CGI.  The program will terminate itself right at that line. Unfortunately, when I check the log file in Apache web server, I don't see anything. As mentioned above, the plain-version of the Perl script works fine in command line. This means I cannot see any error message.

If I replace "gdBrushed" with "$color", the CGI script won't crash. But the point that the statement is supposed to draw doesn't appear in the graphic file. ($color is defined inside the same sub routine, and it is used to draw a line). This means this is really not a solution.

For now, I get around this problem by commenting out that line and skip drawing that "point".  But I would like to find a better solution.

Please note that when I tried to install GD.pm and Chart::Lines to Perl, the normal process failed to install (because the installation program cannot find GD.pm or Chart::Lines in CPAN any more). I ended up using the brutal force approach to copy the entire Perl program folder from a "known good" Apache web server (Windows 7) to the new server (Windows 10).  This may have to do with this problem.  But everything else that I use in Chart::Lines is working, except for drawing that "point".

UPDATE 1:  Fixed the problem with installation of GD and Chart. Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem mentioned in this post. The Chart program still crashes when it tries to draw points. I find the error message in error.log in Apache web server:

```
Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/GD.pm line 87.
```

The statement in GD.pm that triggers the error is:

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    # This AUTOLOAD is used to 'autoload' constants from the constant()
    # XS function.  If a constant is not found then control is passed
    # to the AUTOLOAD in AutoLoader.

    my($constname);
    ($constname = $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
    undef $!;
    my $val = constant($constname);
    if ($! != 0) {
       if ($! =~ /Invalid/) {
           $AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD = $AUTOLOAD;
           goto &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD;
       }
       else {
           my($pack,$file,$line) = caller;
           die "Your vendor has not defined GD macro $pack\:\:$constname, used at $file line $line $!.\n";
       }
    }
    eval "sub $AUTOLOAD { $val }"; <-- This triggers the error
    goto &$AUTOLOAD;
}
```

Seem like the problem may have to do with my program using gdBrushed constant. And somehow using that constant triggers this error in GD.pm. And I don't know why.

UPDATE 2:  I find that when the error happens, $AUTOLOAD has "GD::gdBrushed" in it. This means this error is likely related to the use of that constant.

Comment: [Chart](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart) contains `Chart::Lines`. [GD](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD) is there as usual.

Comment: I used PPM to attempt to install Chart and GD.  But when I used "search" command in PPM to see a list of available distributions, it showed nothing.  That's why I cannot install Chart and GD.  I tried doing this in multiple PCs, and I got the same result ("search" command shows nothing).  I also tried forcing the install by "install GD" and "install Chart" in PPM.  But that didn't work either.  Seem like our computers cannot see any distribution for Perl.

Comment: @JayC *"I used PPM to attempt to install Chart and GD"*:  If you are using strawberry perl, try use `cpanm` instead to install the modules

Comment: Thanks.  I have just tried cpanm to install GD.  This is a bit better because at least it can find the GD distribution.  But it says that it fails to install a dependency "ExtUtils::MakeMaker".  This in turn prevents a dependency "ExtUtils-PkConfig" from being installed because it depends on ExtUtils::MakeMaker.  This in turn prevents GD from being installed.  I check the build.log; it says the same thing.  So close, yet so far...

Comment: The relevant error message in build.log is:

Configuring ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.64
Running Makefile.PL
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.64. See C:\Users\..user..name..\.cpanm\work\1654799538.4956\build.log for details.

I don't know what this error message means.

Comment: I finally figured out the reason why GD and Chart could not be installed correctly (with the help from Håkon Hægland).  The PATH of the computer was missing several paths (such as C:\Windows\System32).  Added the missing paths, and the installation went fine.  Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the problem mentioned in this post.  But I dig deeper and find the error message, and I will put the "real" error message in the main body of my post.